# Example of a non-singular endomorphism that is not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need an example of a non-singular endomorphism that is not invertible. Any hints? I know it must be on an infinite-dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ the vector space of all real sequences and $T,S:V \to V$ be defined by

$T(x_1,x_2,...)=(0,x_1,x_2,...)$ and $S(x_1,x_2,...)=(x_2,x_3,...)$.

Then $T$ is injective but not surjective and $S$ is surjective but not injective.

Do these example help ? One remark: sometimes " non-singular "= "invertible". What is your definition of " non-singular " ?

Comment: thanks. By non-singular I mean it has a trivial kernel. T satisfies this.