# definition of singular endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, definition

What is the definition of singular endomorphism? I cannot find a definition on the web.
I have found a hint that it might be defined as an endomorphism with non-trivial kernel. Is that correct definition?

Comment: $A$ is singular iff $\det(A)=0$ for finite-dimensional vector spaces; otherwise, yes, with non-trivial kernel -  see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457416/example-of-a-non-singular-endomorphism-that-is-not-invertible).